# No access to file system by tomcat service (linux)

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I am running a webapplication with apache-tomcat-7.0.50. My applcication stores files uploaded by the user in a directory of the file system (./opt/data). When I manually start the server as root user with $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh I get access to the file system and all images are visible on my website. I do not want to execute tomcat as root as I think this might be a security issue and I automatically want to start tomcat when the server reboots. So I use a script to start the server as a service:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                #                                                                                                                                                                                                          # tomcat7     This shell script takes care of starting and stopping Tomcat                                                                                                                                 
# Description: This shell script takes care of starting and stopping Tomcat
# chkconfig: - 80 20
#
## Source function library.
#. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
TOMCAT_HOME=/home/peter/tomcat
SHUTDOWN_WAIT=20

tomcat_pid() {
  echo `ps aux | grep org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'`
}

start() {
  pid=$(tomcat_pid)
  if [ -n "$pid" ] 
  then
    echo "Tomcat is already running (pid: $pid)"
  else
    # Start tomcat
    echo "Starting tomcat"
    ulimit -n 100000
    umask 007
    /bin/su -p -s /bin/sh root $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/startup.sh
  fi


  return 0
}

stop() {
  pid=$(tomcat_pid)
  if [ -n "$pid" ]
  then
    echo "Stoping Tomcat"
    /bin/su -p -s /bin/sh root $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh

    let kwait=$SHUTDOWN_WAIT
    count=0;
    until [ `ps -p $pid | grep -c $pid` = '0' ] || [ $count -gt $kwait ]
    do
      echo -n -e "\nwaiting for processes to exit";
      sleep 1
      let count=$count+1;
    done

    if [ $count -gt $kwait ]; then
      echo -n -e "\nkilling processes which didn't stop after $SHUTDOWN_WAIT seconds"
      kill -9 $pid
    fi
  else
    echo "Tomcat is not running"
  fi

  return 0
}

case $1 in
start)
  start
;; 
stop)   
  stop
;; 
restart)
  stop
  start
;;
status)
  pid=$(tomcat_pid)
  if [ -n "$pid" ]
  then
    echo "Tomcat is running with pid: $pid"
  else
    echo "Tomcat is not running"
  fi
;; 
esac
exit 0
```

Unfortunatelly my images cannot be displayed on the website if I start tomcat as a service.

I already gave the directory the following read / write / execute permission:

`drwxrwxrwx 2 root tomandruser     12288 Jan 21 21:09 data`

The user roup tomandruser:

```
[root@s17139702 init.d]# groups root
root : root tomandruser
[root@s17139702 init.d]# groups tomcat
tomcat : tomcat tomandruser
[root@s17139702 init.d]#
```

How can I specify which user runs the tomcat service and how can I get him access to the /opt/data directory so that my server can load the images?

Thanks for helping me out.

Update result ps -aef | grep java

started as service:

```
[root@s17139702 init.d]# ps -aef | grep java
root     28898     1  2 14:21 pts/0    00:01:01 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/endorsed -classpath /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50 -Dcatalina.home=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root     29066 28724  0 14:58 pts/0    00:00:00 grep java
```

started manually:

```
[root@s17139702 bin]# ps -aef | grep java
root     29147     1 99 14:59 pts/0    00:00:11 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/endorsed -classpath /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50 -Dcatalina.home=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root     29165 28724  0 14:59 pts/0    00:00:00 grep java
```

** Update II **

Ok, I created the user updated the user permissions for the directories and subdirectories.

```
drwxr-xr-x 9 tomcatuser tomcatuser      4096 Jan 21 15:09 apache-tomcat-7.0.50
drwxrwxrwx 2 tomcatuser tomcatuser     12288 Jan 21 21:09 data
```

I adjusted the start script:
before: `/bin/su -p -s /bin/sh root $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/startup.sh`

after:  `sudo -u tomcatuser /bin/sh $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/startup.sh`

and call the service like so:

```
sudo service tomcat7 start
```

Still not displaying the images. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate that.

Comment: Use `ps -aef | grep java` and you'll know the user it is running as

Comment: Depending on the distribution, are you running into SELinux issues?

Comment: CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script that you have pasted runs tomcat as root user and it's definitely not what you want to do.

This is what you should do:

- create user say `tomcatuser`
- change owner of tomcat directory and all resources directories to this
  user (`chown -R tomcatuser:tomcatuser <directory>`)
- start service as this user by: `sudo -u tomcatuser <command>`

Comment: Right answer! I finally had to redeploy my application. Thank you!